# Integer counts wrong

Tags: java, member, static-members

I'm working on a big project, but for this question I write a simple example of the problem. I have 2 classes.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CustomType[] customType = new CustomType[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            customType[i] = new CustomType(i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Main " + customType[i].integer);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomType
{
    public static int integer;

    public CustomType(int input)
    {
        integer = input;
        System.out.println("CustomType: " + integer);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
CustomType: 0
CustomType: 1
CustomType: 2
Main 2
Main 2
Main 2
```

but I want to get this:

```
CustomType: 0
CustomType: 1
CustomType: 2
Main: 0
Main: 1
Main: 2
```

Comment: You misunderstood what `static` means. You probably wanted `integer` to be not `static`.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is because you're using a `static` variable for `integer`.

A static variable is common to all the instances of an object or class (in your case your `CustomType` class). Put simply, a single copy of your static variable is created and shared amongst all the instances of your class.

So when you create your `CustomType` object at index 0 of your `for` loop, the static variable value is 0 for all instances. When index position 1 of the array is used, it changes to 1 for all instances. When your `for` loop ends at index position 2, the `static` variable finishes with a value of 2 for all instances.

What you need to do, instead, is use:
`public int integer`

This will give each `CustomType` object its own individual `integer` variable which will be assigned with the correct values that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to have different values for each object then don't make the variable static, rather set it to private and make a getter method to retrieve your private var.

This

```
 public static int integer;
```

to

```
 private int integer;
```

And your getter method will retrieve the data

```
public int getInt()
{
    return integer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I removed that static keyword and my project has no problems : D

Answer (score 0):

`static` is the hint..

Why would you think a `static` variable would be bind to a specific instance in the first place?

Try using `public int integer;` instead of `public static int integer;` and look at the magic behind instance variables.